# OOD : What is this -> Object keeping references of its own class?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am dealing with OO for several years now, and sometimes I see a class, which has an attribute ( a list or table usually  ) which holds references to itself and other objects of the same type.

Is there a name for this pattern ?
What is the usual case to use this and why ?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Seems like a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)?

Comment: If its a linked list its not necessarily in OOPs. A struct in C can do the same

Comment: Also, if you add a small snippet showing how exactly the pattern is maybe our experts here can help better.

Comment: A little bit difficult.
It is an ABAP, class designer.
Should I perhaps redirect the question there ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a very usual case. For instance a table which contains a foreign key to itself :

```
Employee
----------
ID
MANAGER_ID (reference to employee)
```

Your JPA/Hibernate entities will hold references to themselves when you are your own boss :-)